# PHP: function arguments' names

Tags: php, anonymous-function

I need to get anonymous function arguments' names.

E.g.:

```
$func = function ( $param1, $param2 ) { ... };
$names = DO_SOMETHING($func); 
// after this $names should become something like array('param1', param2')
```

Theoretically, it is possible because `var_dump($func)` says that `$func` is the object of `Closure` class and have `parameter` property which is `array('param1', 'param2')`.

Official documentation at php.net describes no methods of Closure class, which can help me.

I've tried to access this property directly, but PHP died with fatal error: `Closure object cannot have properties`.

I've tried to get object vars by `get_object_vars` but it seems the `parameter` property is declated as private (anyway, `get_object_vars` does not return it).

The only one way I know -- to intercept the output of `var_dump` and parse it, but as we easily understand this is not the way we should write our scripts =)

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: @Felix I need to call a callback for every request. Callback's parameters are formed from URL and parsed by regexp. As a result we have list of values, but their order can be different from callback's parameters order. E.g.: request `/hello/{username}/{email}`, but callback `function($email, $username) { ... }`.  In source this scheme looks like: `Request('/hello/{username}/{email}', function($email, $username) { ... });`

Comment: (Assuming you have control over `Request`): It looks to me that it would be better to pass an array of parameters to the callback: `array('username' => 'value', 'email' => 'value')`. Then one does not have to worry about the order.

Comment: @Felix: I considered JS-style approach, but decided, that this described approach is more understandable and beautiful. At least visually.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Can't try this at the moment, but have a look at:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionfunction.php

especially

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionfunctionabstract.getparameters.php

Maybe this will do the trick.

Edit:
Try this:

```
$func = function ( $param1, $param2 ) {
    /* some code */
};

$refFunc = new ReflectionFunction($func);
foreach ($refFunc->getParameters() as $refParameter) {
    echo $refParameter->getName(), '<br />';
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this should do it. You can pass in the the closure (`$func` in this case) to the ReflectionFunction constructor -- see http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionfunction.construct.php

Comment: Yep! That's what I'm talking about =) Thanks.